# Django error no such table: auth_group when running makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

When i run `python manage.py makemigrations`
it throws an error:

```
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/smoke/Documents/wsl_dev/testing/genelookup/apps/authentication/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .views import login_view, register_user
  File "/home/smoke/Documents/wsl_dev/testing/genelookup/apps/authentication/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    compute, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='compute')
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smoke/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_group
```

I discovered the problem was in one of my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm, SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group  # error 
from apps.utils import unauthenticated_user

# create groups
compute, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='compute') # Error 
search, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='search') # error

@unauthenticated_user
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    msg = None

    if request.method == "POST":
...
```

If i comment out the lines marked with comment error and then run the migrations, it works perfectly fine. But this workaround is not suitable for deploying into production is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines from your error stacktrace show that you are importing views into your `urls.py`

```
File "/home/smoke/Documents/wsl_dev/testing/genelookup/apps/authentication/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .views import login_view, register_user
  File "/home/smoke/Documents/wsl_dev/testing/genelookup/apps/authentication/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    compute, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='compute')
```

And in your views.py you are importing the Group model. This is a common import order issue for django apps. What happens here is when your app is started, it goes through your `urls.py` first before your models are loaded, and because of the import statements you have you are loading the models before they are registered.

Instead of having these lines on `views.py`, try move them into the functions where you need them. That should resolve the issue.

```
# create groups
compute, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='compute') # Error 
search, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='search') # error
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the amazing explaination.